# How to get PropertyChanged events work with bindings using converters?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` bound to a list of objects and for each item in the `ListBox` there is a `TextBlock` bound with a converter but when the properties of the objects change, I can't get those `TextBlock` updated while I can get them updated if not bound with a converter.

The xmal of the window is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingPropertyChanged.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingPropertyChanged"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:LocationToTextConverter x:Key="LocationToTextConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox
            Grid.Row="2"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
          >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NameText" 
                            Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LocationToTextConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="DescriptionText"
                            Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Place" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Places}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.PlaceId}"
                SelectedValuePath="Id"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                IsEditable="False"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Description" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Description, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

On the left is the aforementioned `ListBox` and on the right are a `TextBox` and a `ComboBox` for authoring the selected item in the `ListBox`. In `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, `DescriptionText` can get updated if I alter the text of `TextBox` on the right while `NameText` cannot get updated because it uses a converter in the binding.

The following code is the classes of the domain model:

```
public class DomainBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberNameAttribute] string propertyName = "None")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class Location : DomainBase
{
    private int _placeId;
    private string _description;

    public int PlaceId
    {
        get { return _placeId; }
        set
        {
            if (_placeId == value) return;
            _placeId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) return;
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class Place : DomainBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There is a `Repository` class for dummy data:

```
public class Repository
{
    public static ICollection<Place> _places;
    public static ICollection<Place> Places
    {
        get { return _places; }
    }

    public static ICollection<Location> _locations;
    public static ICollection<Location> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
    }

    static Repository()
    {
        _places = new List<Place>();
        _places.Add(new Place() { Id = 1, Name = "Downtown Center" });
        _places.Add(new Place() { Id = 2, Name = "Headquarter" });

        _locations = new List<Location>();
        _locations.Add(new Location() { PlaceId = 1, Description = "Room 101" });
        _locations.Add(new Location() { PlaceId = 2, Description = "B06" });
    }
}
```

And the `ViewModel` class set to the `DataContext` of the window:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Location> _items = new ObservableCollection<Location>(Repository.Locations);
    private Location _selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<Location> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (_items == value) return;
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
    public Location SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value) return;
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Place> Places
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Place>(Repository.Places);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "None")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the converter:

```
class LocationToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = "";
        Location location = value as Location;
        if (location != null)
        {
            Place place = Repository.Places.Single(o => o.Id == location.PlaceId);
            if (place != null)
            {
                string placeName = place.Name;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(placeName))
                {
                    result = placeName + ", ";
                }
            }

            result += location.Description;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What I want is to display the `Place`'s `Name` with the `Location`'s `Description` in the `ListBox` and when I alter the selected `Location`'s `Description`, the display name in the `ListBox` should be changed instantly as well. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: I think the problem is, that the `Location` does not invoke a `PropertyChanged` because the `Location` object itself is not changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is here

```
                    <TextBlock x:Name="NameText" 
                        Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LocationToTextConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

In your binding you didn't specify a path.  When you did this, the item that gets binded will be a location object.  Since you are changing the Descrition property of the Location object and not the Location object itself, TextBlock is not getting the property changed notification.

You only need to change a few lines of code, use a MultiBinding instead.

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding>
        <Binding />
        <Binding Path=Description />
        //dont forget to specify the converter
....
class LocationToTextConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    //in the Convert method set, ignore value[1] and change location to values[0]
    Location location = values[0] as Location;
```

now your converter should get called anytime you change the description property.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Also I have to bind "PlaceId" to the TextBlock.

Comment: MultiBinding is correct. Raising PropertyChanged("PlaceId") on a Description change is a kludge, and since PlaceId won't have changed, the Binding might not even fall for it. Not gonna bother testing it. Cheers

Comment: Well, PlaceId is changeable because there is a ComboBox for it on the right of the window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Location` is not changed so the `NotifyPropertyChanged` is not invoked. The easiest solution is to create property on the `Location`. So there are two option how you can do it:

- Call the `OnPropertyChanged("Location")` from `Location` so that it is triggered
- Add an own property on the `Location` and bind to this property instead of the `Location`

Comment: This ought to work too. The only trouble is that if you define a Location property on Location called Location, the compiler's going to tell you to pull the other one ("Member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"). `public Location Self { get { return this; } }` would be fine though, then `OnPropertyChanged("Self")`

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah this would also be possible. I have not tried the code so this was only a assumption :D

Answer (score 0):

why not just have a property and bind to it?

```
public class Location : DomainBase
{
    private int _placeId;
    private string _description;

    public int PlaceId
    {
        get { return _placeId; }
        set
        {
            if (_placeId == value) return;
            _placeId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) return;
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();  // make sure  this Notify RepPlusDescription
        }
    }

    public string RepPlusDescription
    {
        get 
        {   
            string result;
            Place place = Repository.Places.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == placeId);
            if (place != null)
            {
                string placeName = place.Name;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(placeName))
                {
                    result = placeName + ", ";
                }
            }
            return result += location.Description; 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I've thought of that, but it's not an ideal solution because I have to add extra properties in classes of the domain model to fit the requirement of UI.

Comment: Oh, no a whole extra property?   Fail to see how that answer requires any thing different of the DomainBase.

Comment: It also violates dependency relationship because Repository depends on Location but Location is not supposed to rely on Repository. Repository here is just a placeholder for test purpose. In real cases, Repository can be from different DB, text files, binary files and so on.

Comment: If you converter depends on it then there is a dependency.   No difference calling Repository.Places in converter versus a get.

Comment: The code I showed here is just an example to demonstrate the situation I had. It seems fine to just add an extra property for that but in my actual application I have four similar bindings so far (and there will be probably more as I continue developing it). That forces me to seek for a better solution.

Comment: What ever, I am not buying that code that can be called in a converter cannot but called get.

Comment: Well, it does make difference because the converter belongs to a WPF application project and in that project repository classes are bound to a DB. But classes of the domain model are in another project and they are supposed to be reused in other applications with different repository classes. It's hard to see here because I don't show you the projects in the solution. I am sorry for that. Moreover, it's easy to remove the dependency of the repository in the converter by making it a public property so it's not the point.

Comment: OK but what is stopping from making a LocationApp that derives from Location that belongs to the WPF application?  I am back to if the code will run in converter it will run get.